# What is the "star" measurement in Expression Blend?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2012, expression-blend

I am currently working on a Windows 8 Metro/Modern UI application. Right now, I'm working on the interface in Expression Blend for Visual Studio.

My question is this: When sizing UI elements such as grid columns, I can use either pixels, auto, or stars. What is a star in this context? A google search turns up nothing and I haven't found anything in the Windiws 8 developer documentation.

Thank you.

Comment: It means `use whatever is left over`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a grid a `*` means that it will equally share available space with other `*` columns (or rows).  There are some good WPF examples of how this works [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768293/what-does-the-wpf-star-do-width-100).

From the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.columndefinition.width):

> starSizing
>
> > A convention by which you can size rows or columns to take
> >     the remaining available space in a Grid. A star sizing always includes
> >     the asterisk character (*), and optionally precedes the asterisk with
> >     an integer value that specifies a weighted factor versus other
> >     possible star sizings (for example, 3*). For more information about
> >     star sizing, see Grid.

Answer (score 2):

In a grid with multiple columns, the * size columns divide up the remaining space.  For example assume a 300px wide grid with 3 columns (150px, 120px and 1*).

The calculation is:

```
remainder = (300 - 150 - 120)
```

Since the remainder is 30px the 1* column is 30px wide

Now add some columns and modify the widths to  (35px, 85px, 2*, 1*, 3*)

Redoing the calculation:

```
remainder = (300 - 35 - 85)
```

In this scenario the remainder is 180px, so each * column splits the remaining pixels according to their weighting number.

```
factor = (180/ (2 + 1 + 3)) 
factor = 30px
```

Therefore the 2* column is 60px, the 1* column is 30px and the 3* column is 90px

```
300 == 35 + 85 + 60 + 30 + 90
```

Of course the same principles apply for Row sizing.

When the grid is resized the * columns divvy up the new remainder size.  But they keep the same size ratio between other * size items.  In the example the 3* column will always be 3 times as wide as the 1* column.