# Why does the '*' in XAML not always work as expected?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm working on a Windows Store App. I'm new to XAML development.

I'm trying to get some elements within a Grid to be sized relative to each other. After looking at questions like this ([What does the WPF star do (Width="100*")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768293/what-does-the-wpf-star-do-width-100)) I thought I had it all figured out. The following example does not seem to do what I expect however.

Instead of seeing 'Foo' on the left and 'Bar' on the further on the right (since Foo's column should be six times the size), I just see 'FooBar'.  Anyone know what is going on?

```
    <Grid Margin="10">
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="6*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

      <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Foo" />
      <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Bar" />
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` on the `<Grid>` element?

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine. But note; I didn't have a `size` on the `Window`..Can you try removing the default size on the `window` element..

Comment: Can we see the `window` element of your `xaml`..If that is the only other code in your `xaml`

Comment: This is actually in a Windows Store app - no Window element. It's also nested pretty deep in a few stack panels and other grids. However, It has one half of the screen all to itself. When I set the column definitions to hard values like 600 and 100, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this tutorial](http://wpftutorial.net/GridLayout.html) star sizing does not work if your grid size is determined by the content (as opposed to its container).  You might try specifying a width for the grid, or having it stretch to fill the container.

Comment: This is more or less the root cause.

In my case, I had this grid as the DataTemplate in a ListView. I needed to set the ItemContainerStyle property of the ListView a certain way to get it so the grid would always fill the container to avoid this issue.