# Why doesn't the grid layout work without specifying RowDefinitions and Column Definitions?

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps

```
<Page
    x:Class="AllControls.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:AllControls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">



        <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Red" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Orange"  Grid.Column="1"  Grid.Row="0"/>
        <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Yellow"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Green" Grid.Column="1"  Grid.Row="1"/>
        <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Blue" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2"/>
        <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Indigo" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"/>
        <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Violet" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3"/>
        <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Purple" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

I am providing, Row Number and Column number for each element in this case Rectangles. I have also provided height and width for each of them.

I come from an HTML background.

Can someone explain to me how the tags RowDefinitions and ColumnDefinitions work here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify RowDefinitions and ColumnDefinitions so that it knows how to size the rows and columns. Otherwise it doesn't know whether you want auto-sizing or [star-sizing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2318082/674077). And it also needs to know how many rows and columns you need up front; it doesn't add them on the fly based on your values of Grid.Row and Grid.Column.

I think the code you wrote looks reasonable, and it would be nice if it used a default when you don't specify, but unfortunately it doesn't. Instead, it builds a single-column, single-row grid and stacks all the children on top of each other.

I can think of a couple ways to write some XAML that will do what you want.

One way:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Red" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Orange"  Grid.Column="1"  Grid.Row="0"/>
    ...
</Grid>
```

Another way:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Fill="Red" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="Orange"  Grid.Column="1"  Grid.Row="0"/>
    ...
</Grid>
```

Comment: so if i want to create a 4x2 grid, I need to provide 4 RowDefinitions and two column definitions ?

Why have you only given three RowDefinitions ? 4th one is automatically arranged or what ?

Is it possible for me to have table like structure where all the rows need not have same number of columns.

Comment: Oops, my mistake. You do need four RowDefinitions, so I have edited my answer. Each row always has the same number of columns, but you can use Grid.ColumnSpan="2" on a rectangle to make it two columns wide (assuming you don't specify an explicit width on the rectangle). Similarly for Grid.RowSpan.

Comment: Thank you. Thanks a lot. I am fed up with every new GUI framework coming up with their own markup language and new layout rules.

Comment: I can sympathize. Lately I've been trying to go the opposite direction as you (I have a XAML background and am learning HTML/CSS), and I'm finding there are some things I need to "unlearn."

Comment: Hey, just wanted to know. How do HTML-CSS-JS based metro apps perform on devices compared to XAML based apps ?

Comment: BTW if you are learning CSS layouts. apart from cross browser problems. You will probably have a hard time understanding layouts.
Here the layouts dont mean as their name suggests.

Go thru this website If you ever get confused with layouts and positioning in CSS.

http://learnlayout.com/

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have the experience to be able to answer your question about performance. Thank you very much for the CSS layout link though! That looks like exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Like Mr. Andrew pointed out, you'll have to define your layout more to accomplish it using specified `RowDefinition` / `ColumnDefinition` to basically manually lay your stuff out. If you're looking for something a bit more fluid with less requirement for defining your layout structure you should look into [GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.gridview) / [VariableSizeWrapGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.variablesizedwrapgrid) (I think is more of what you're looking for.)

Both of which have multiple [examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh969155.aspx) available around the web and are pretty simple to get used to. Hope this helps on your transition from HTML to XAML (ps, in my opinion XAML > HTML)

:)