# How to make resolution independent apps windows phone 8.1?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

Its given that the os automatically adjusts the components if using grid with auto and * but it never happens, view components are small in larger screen sizes

What is the proper way?

Comment: Look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768293/what-does-the-wpf-star-do-width-100, you can set some ratios so you do not depend on a fixed size

Comment: @dkg thanks for the answer but suppose i give a textbox width of 300 then the textbox is coming smaller in big screen sizes .how to fix that?

Comment: You can use `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` to fill the space instead of setting a fixed size.