# How to make the button one third of the size of the window? WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, button, size

I want to specify the width of my button in percent.
Is there something like width: 33% in WPF?
this is my button:

```
<Button x:Name="btnWebsite" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="58,342,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="43" Width="139"/>
```

thanks for the help :D

Comment: I think something (image, code) did not show up in your question.

Comment: You can get the width of the form and modify the width of your button using it.  Use `.ActualHeight` and `.ActualWidth` to get the actual values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put the `Button` in a [star-sized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768293/what-does-the-wpf-star-do-width-100) `Grid` that fills the window:

```
<Window ...>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Button Content="..." Grid.Column="1" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Or handle the `SizeChanged` event of the window and set the button's `Width` property to `this.Width / 3.0`:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SizeChanged += OnSizeChanged;
    }

    private void OnSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        btnWebsite.Width = Width / 3.0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i really appreciate that!

Comment: When I maximize the window with the Maximize button, the button does not adjust. How can I change this?

Comment: It should adjust using my sample markup, i.e. if the `Grid` is the `Content` of the window being maximized.